# Use Python to search and pull data from Excel

Tags: python, excel, csv, python-3.x

```
import csv

subject = ['emergency*', 'new ticket*', 'problem with*']
from_to = ['chris*', 'timothy*', 'daniel*', 'david*', 'jason*']

a = open('D:\testfile.csv', 'w')
```

New to python. So, here's what I'd like to do.

1) Open an excel csv file

2) Search for specific keywords that are in a list

3) If the keywords are found, pull the data that is in the D,E,F columns only. (Since that is where the keywords will be)

4) Write this data to a new file

Example. Search testfile.csv for any of the keywords in the from_to list. If these keywords appear ONLY in the D or E columns of excel AND if the corresponding column F is not equal to the subject list, then write a new file that has the columns of D,E,F and the associated lines, however many there are, with it

Also, I put the stars next to the names/items in the list to denote a wildcard, eg if the from_to contains chris.gmail.com or daniel@yahoo.

Answer (score 0):

This solution has a list of keywords, an input file that you read line by line, tokenize each line into a list of strings, then iterate your keyword list to check if any of them is in the tokenized line. If any keyword is found it writes the line to the output file.

```
keywrds = ["word1", "word2", "etc"]
with open ("myfile.csv") as fin:
    with open ("outfile.txt") as fout:
        for line in fin:
            line_tokens = line.split(",")
            for word in keywrds:
                if word in line_tokens:
                    fout.write(line_tokens[3:6].join(" ") + "\n")
```

Comment: Thanks. Would the *'s I use work as wildcard's in the lists? And how would I combine the look with an and statement to make sure the subject keyword list was not matched?

Comment: no, your wildcard * will not work. I can't think of any easy way to implement that. For the extra check, you need to add another for loop inside the if statement that loops through the subject keywords to check if any of them are in line_tokens.